# XML read column and add new data based off date format

Tags: text-processing

I have the following data in a XML document

```
NAME    19/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:21    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
NAME    19/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:22    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
NAME    22/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:23    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
NAME    23/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:24    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
NAME    23/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:25    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
NAME    23/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:26    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
```

The columns are

```
   Client Name  Creation Date   Due Date    Date Paid   Subtotal    Credit  Total   Status  Payment Method
```

I need to convert this data to the following below. The new column added at the start would be the date that the invoice was generated followed by numerical order for that day based off the order they are in my document, not the time eg 13:21. Each day should start back at 1.

```
19-02-2019-1    NAME    19/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:21    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
19-02-2019-2    NAME    19/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:22    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
22-02-2019-1    NAME    22/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:23    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
23-02-2019-1    NAME    23/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:24    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
23-02-2019-2    NAME    23/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:25    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
23-02-2019-3    NAME    23/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:26    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
```

How am I able to do this? Preferably with perl but anything will work.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Do you want to add a new field in the `xml` file or just process the output text to add the extra column at the start? If it's the first option then you need to post a sample showing the structure of the `xml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to amend the text output from your `xml`/`xpath` then pipe it through `awk` like ....

```
sort -k2 file1 | awk '{head[$2]++;print $2"-"head[$2], $0}'
```

Output

```
19/02/2019-1 NAME    19/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:21    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
19/02/2019-2 NAME    19/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:22    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
22/02/2019-1 NAME    22/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:23    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
23/02/2019-1 NAME    23/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:24    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
23/02/2019-2 NAME    23/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:25    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
23/02/2019-3 NAME    23/02/2019  23/02/2019  23/02/2019 13:26    12.99   0   12.99   Paid    PayPal
```

If your output is already sorted then just `cat file1` instead of `sort`ing.